# multiple instance of a certain microservice writing to database at same time

Tags: java, concurrency, microservices

I have multiple instances of a certain microservice for ex 5 instances they accessing a database table at the same time which causes a lock on that table, how can I make a suitable solution to prevent locking?
is messaging queue will solve the problem?

Comment: What is wrong with locking? What are you trying to achieve with your app? For example, do you need ordered writes?

Answer (score 1):

What is the database? Most modern databases support row-level locking, so if you update a row it will not affect other queries to the same table.

Comment: MySQL, these instances sometimes update/inseart/ delete from the same table at the same time which causes locking

Comment: @dev_2020 are you on MyISAM or InnoDB? InnoDB uses row-level locking.

Comment: we using InnoDB

Comment: @dev_2020 in that case you shouldn't have a problem with table locking.